# sorting polygons extracted using Fishnet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry, vector-grid

I generated polygons using fishnet in ArcMap, since the polygons didn't fall exactly on top of my raster image, I had to edit and move some of them. Now the FID of my polygons are all messed up, and are not in the order that I want them to be (I want them to start from top right and end at the bottom left).

I tried calculating the centroid of the polygons and sort them based on that, but it doesn't work since not all the polygons are in line. I attach a picture.[image: Polygons extracted from Fishnet and edited]

Comment: FID cannot be edited. That is controlled by the software. On edit it re-arranges the FID (retires splits and updates) and (creates new for both or all splits) you should use another field to do a join. Which you should also edit your question to be more clear. I am just guessing that you want to do a join. (I been down that road).

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [Sort Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000057000000).  It can be used to sort by attribute, or more importantly for you, spatially.  It allows you to pick which corner (i.e. upper right) to give priority when sorting.